# wordpress site is only displaying 5 posts

Tags: wordpress

It's a custom post page which should output all posts - is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array();
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <li><?php posted_on(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> &raquo</a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see 5 post because it's default value in your wordpress admin. 
It's not 100% right way, but you can do the same by using this construction:

```
<?php
$myposts = get_posts('cat=1&numberposts=-1&');
foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>

<?php the_time(__('d/m/Y')) ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where "cat" - category name/ID. Also you can try to remove "cat=" if you need all categories.

Comment: You should escape dynamically generated content in your Theme, especially content that is output to HTML attributes. Please, find out more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Untrusted_Data